# prove that 0 is not a subsequential limit of this sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_n=(-1)^n +\frac{2}{n}$. 
Prove that $0$ is not a subsequential limit of the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

If there is some subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})$ of $(x_{n})$ such that $x_{n_{k}} \to 0$ as $k$ grows indefinitely, then there is some $N \geq 1$ such that
$|x_{n_{k}} - 0| = |x_{n_{k}}| < 1/2$ for all $k \geq N$; but $|x_{n}| = |(-1)^{n} + \frac{2}{n}| > 1/2$ for all $n \geq 4$.

Comment: IS this enough  ?